# Python Pdfkit small black box instead of content

Tags: python, pdfkit

I'm using pdfkit to convert html to pdf. But there is an error like above.

[image: Pdf Screenshot]

```
options = {
    'page-size': 'A4',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'dpi' : 400,
    'custom-header': [
        ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    ]
}


pdfkit.from_url(file_path, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/pdf") + file_name,options=options)

return redirect(file_path)
```

Comment: What code are you using to generate a pdf? Could you provide a sample of the HTML that you use?

Comment: @Hoog simple html tempate that contains "lorem ipsum dolar sit amet", by the way  update codes.